# Error while executing django sphinx

Tags: django, python-sphinx

I have installed django sphinx for my project.After successful installation and sphinx quickstart operation, i tried for creating html inside the "build" folder using the command "make html" and it gives me the error 
"make: *** No rule to make target `html'.  Stop.".
Any help..Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a package called [django-sphinx](https://github.com/dcramer/django-sphinx). But this question looks like it is about [the other Sphinx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-sphinx), since "quickstart" and "make html" are mentioned.

Comment: @mzjn i'm sure that using django sphinx in my project and the same was installed in the project.But don't know why this results in error???

Comment: @mzjn I m extremely sorry. I m using python sphinx in my project. So how can i proceed now?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In for sphinx-doc (i have never used django-sphinx) it would never work to run `make html` inside the build folder. You need to go one folder level up so that the folders build and source ar visible. Most likely you will see the `Makefile` file here as well.

Try to change directories and run `make html` again.